# Is this the right way of sending realtime messages in firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

like a lot of threads I've seen my messages does arrive in realtime and some times doesn't, they take a lot of time.

I wanted to know If what I'm doing is the right way or Am I doing something wrong?.

This is the code that send messages in my back-end; is made in java using tomcat.

```
FCMService.init();
    Message message = Message.builder()
            .putData("notification", "Tienes un mesaje")
            .setToken(googleToken.getmFCMtoken())
            .setAndroidConfig(
                    AndroidConfig.builder()
                            .setPriority(AndroidConfig.Priority.HIGH)
                            .build()
            ).build();

return FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendAsync(message).get();
```

(I omit the try and catch)

`FCMService` is a wrapper I made to initialize the FCM-SDK and `googleToken` is an object that contains the user and the firebase id.

Am I missing something in order to make the messages really realtime?.

Comment: There are no guarantees about the latency of delivery, but they are normally very fast.  It very much depends on the many, many systems that exist between your server, FCM servers, and your app.

Comment: Yea I just figure that I was storing things in the DB before sending the message and I just change it and it's faster (facepalm), but still, Is this the right way? Is there any other config I'm missing?